# Function approximating camels humps?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, stationary-point

I want to construct a function with two maxima and a minima in between that would approximate the two humps of a camel.
In addition, I would like that there would be some effort (not a polynomial) to find the derivatives. And I would also like that the stationary points and inflection points can be evaluated without a calculator.

The closest I got was the function $$\ln(8 - \frac{1}{4}x^4 + 3 x^2 - 4 x),$$
but the inflection points are not nice.

Comment: I think tasks like this are closer to art than mathematics. It's an artform, choosing the correct functions and coefficients.

Comment: Well, I'm not trying to get the real-life curve, I just want to create an exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this function? $$f(x)=2e^{-x^2}+2e^{-(x-2)^2}-e^{-(x-1)^2}$$

Its graph looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Good idea to use normal distributions!